# DirectX11 CreateSharedHandle - is this cross-device?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, directx, gpu

I'm using `CreateShaderHandle` to create a handle to a `IDXGIResource1` keyed shared resource. The goal is to grab this resource in a thread and use it into another thread.

For now I'm creating a D3D11 device on both threads **on the same adapter**

```
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(dxgi_adapter, ...);
```

and sharing this handle works.

It doesn't seem to work if, on the consumer thread, I create the device on *another* adapter.

So my question is: does a `CreateShaderHandle` handle in D3D11 only work on the same adapter (gpu)?

Comment: To my best knowledge it's same adapter only. The sharing in first place assumes that resources are backed by the same data, same fragment of video memory. So different adapters need their own copy of the data, hence no sharing via keyed mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN articles on cross-device sharing and related to use of DXGI keyed mutexes are not giving the answer explicitly, however MSDN still has it, in [`IDXGIFactory2::GetSharedResourceAdapterLuid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404560):

> You cannot share resources across adapters. Therefore, you cannot open a shared resource on an adapter other than the adapter on which the resource was created. 
>   [...] ...before you open a shared resource to ensure that the resource was created on the appropriate adapter.

That is, "same adapter only" resource sharing.